# ¿Debo de hacer una llamada get a una API cada vez que tenga que hacer un post o un put para poder actualizar el estado manejado con redux?

Tags: api, redux, restful, react-redux

Para actualizar el estado de redux al hacer una llamada http post o put necesito hacer nuevamente una llamada get para actualizar el estado?, He visto en algunos tutoriales que al hacer llamadas put o post no hacen ninguna otra llamada get si no que actualizan el estado en ambas partes por separado, por ejemplo:

```
// action.js

export const addOrder = (data) => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const date = new Date();
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://dummy-api`,
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
    //**********************************************************
        //se envia la información al servidor
        body: JSON.stringify({
           **data**
        }),
      }
    );

    const resData = await response.json();

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("Something went wrong!");
    }
    //**********************************************************
     //se actualiza la información localmente con los parametros a enviar
    dispatch({
      type: ADD_ORDER,
      orderData: {
        **data**
      },
    });
  };
};
```

Pero mi problema es que yo al hacer una una llamada put o post, en el backend tengo varias tablas que se actualizan, no sólo una, y creo que realmente hacer todas esas actualizaciones en el front sería un poco difícil, ya que la api no regresa nada de información más que el estado de la petición.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que el store de redux guarda estados basándose en información proveniente de alguna fuente (API, Websocket, etc), por lo que si deseas tener disponible la información actualizada en el front, sí deberías realizar un nuevo request hacia tu back (para tu caso). O, podrías basarte en si el POST o PUT fue exitoso y actualizar la información basándote en lo que enviaste hacia tu back. No sé si me hice entender

Comment: Muchas gracias, creo que haré una nueva petición al back ya que actualizar el estado de redux basándome en lo que envío hacia al back sería un poco difícil ya se que se actualizan muchas tablas en la base de datos.